# How to convert string with wrong Turkish characters to show the correct characters?

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a string with ASCII characters like

```
"Tu%C4%9F%C3%A7e%20Kandemir%20-%20G%C3%BCl%C3%BC%20Soldurmam.mp3"
```

The correct filename is

```
"Tuğçe Kandemir - Gülü Soldurmam"
```

How can I convert it?

Comment: There is a article you should read: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ | If those are troly ASCII, not unicode, it is going to be a pain in the behind to deal with.

Comment: @Christopher: It's really not. The string is ASCII (in that every character within it is in the ASCII set), but it's just URL-encoded Unicode (via UTF-8).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That string looks like its been encoded for a URL.

You can use [`UrlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.8) from `System.Web.HttpUtility`:

```
var encoded = "Tu%C4%9F%C3%A7e%20Kandemir%20-%20G%C3%BCl%C3%BC%20Soldurmam.mp3";
var decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encoded);
```

Or if you're not using a web application, you can use [`System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var decoded = WebUtility.UrlDecode(encoded);
```

Both of these output the following string:

```
"Tuğçe Kandemir - Gülü Soldurmam.mp3"
```

Answer (score 4):

That's just URL-encoded using UTF-8 as the encoding - it's easy to decode with [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpUtility_UrlDecode_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_). Here's a complete program demonstrating that:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string encoded = "Tu%C4%9F%C3%A7e%20Kandemir%20-%20G%C3%BCl%C3%BC%20Soldurmam.mp3";
        string decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encoded, Encoding.UTF8);
        foreach (char c in decoded)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{c}: U+{(int) c:X4}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output - on a console set to UTF-8 just to make sure all characters can be displayed, but I've printed out the Unicode numbers as well, for clarity:

```
T: U+0054
u: U+0075
ğ: U+011F
ç: U+00E7
e: U+0065
 : U+0020
K: U+004B
a: U+0061
n: U+006E
d: U+0064
e: U+0065
m: U+006D
i: U+0069
r: U+0072
 : U+0020
-: U+002D
 : U+0020
G: U+0047
ü: U+00FC
l: U+006C
ü: U+00FC
 : U+0020
S: U+0053
o: U+006F
l: U+006C
d: U+0064
u: U+0075
r: U+0072
m: U+006D
a: U+0061
m: U+006D
.: U+002E
m: U+006D
p: U+0070
3: U+0033
```